# Salesforce Chatter - Reply to

Tags: chatter

After the latest Winter 24' requirement about Chatter (https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_experiences_require_sender_email_release_update.htm&release=246&type=5), we have put a shared mailbox to that email field.
We have deselected the option 'Allow Email Replies', however people are still being able to Reply to these notifications.
Any ideas?

Comment: Have you disabled 'Allow Posts via Email' and 'Allow Emails' settings as well? If no can you disable and check.